# Validar Captcha para site com acessibilidade

Tags: html5, acessibilidade

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário do qual será acessível. Para isso, o campo captcha estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
 <div class="control-group">
           <div class="controls">
              <?php
              $codigoCaptcha = substr(md5(time()) ,0, 5);
              if(!isset($_SESSION["Captcha"])){
                 $_SESSION["Captcha"] = $codigoCaptcha;
              }
               echo "<div id='captcha'>".$_SESSION["Captcha"]."</div>";
              ?>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Captcha" title="Digite o código <?php echo $_SESSION["Captcha"]; ?>" required />
           </div>
     </div>

....
</html>
<?php unset($_SESSION["Captcha"]); ?>
```

O leitor de tela consegue ler o captcha corretamente, porém se digitarmos errado o captcha ele envia. É possível criar uma validação através do HTML5 para esse caso, lembrando que o leitor de tela só lê (até onde sei) os campos com o required?

Comment: Não teria que fazer uma validação via JavaScript para ver se o código foi digitado correto?

Comment: Olá dvd. Tentei fazer a validação do formulário em javascript, porém o leitor de tela não leu com tanta clareza como ocorre na validação com HTML5 e isso pode confundir um pouco quem precisa da acessibilidade.